# Beautifulsoup parse Selenium element

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, element

I use `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)` to parse the whole page from Selenium in BeautifulSoup.

But how to just parse one element of Selenium in BeautifulSoup.

Below code will throw

> TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_name)
soup = BeautifulSoup(element)
```

Comment: try BeautifulSoup(element.text, 'lxml'), lxml is the parser

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed `element.text` will just return the text, and lost all the tag.

Comment: You want to get an element say like `<div> Hi </div>` , right?

Comment: Yes, It may have many sub tag in it.

Comment: I answered, have a look

Comment: I tested & it's working, be sure to try the code after I edited & fixed the typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if selenium does this out of the box, but I managed to find this workaround

```
element_html = f"<{element.tag_name}>{element.get_attribute('innerHTML')}</{element.tag_name}>"
```

you may want to replace `innerHTML` with `innerTEXT` if you want to get only the text, for example

```
<li>Hi <span> man </span> </li>
```

Getting the innerHTML will return all of what inside but the innerTEXT won't, try & see.

now create your `Soup` object

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(element_html)
print(soup.WHATEVER)
```

using the above technique, just create a method `parseElement(webElement)` & use it whenever you want to parse an element.

**Btw I only use lxml & when I forgot to type it, the script didn't work**